# increase value of math.random

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi i am trying to increase the value of 'setLinearVelocity' every 60 second by 10.

```
badclouts:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(100, 150)) -- Drop down

local function setLinearVelocityTimer()
   LinearVelocityTimer= timer.performWithDelay( badclouts, setLinearVelocity, 0 )
   LinearVelocityTimer= setLinearVelocity +10
   --print("time1 " .. setLinearVelocity)
end

countdownTimer()
local mainTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 6000, setLinearVelocityTimer, 10 )
```

I have tried this but whiteout any success, any help is is much appreciated.

Regards Kevin,

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you was trying to do this:

```
badclouts:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(100, 150)) -- Drop down

local function increaseYVelocity()
   local vx, vy = badclouts:getLinearVelocity()
   vy = vy + 10
   badclouts:setLinearVelocity(vx, vy)
   --print("y component of linear velocity: " .. vy)
end

countdownTimer()  --I don't know nothing about this function

local mainTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 6000, increaseYVelocity, 10 )
```

Comment: this is not increasing the value

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and add some more details.